# A user can only create an account from a device

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Is there any way that a user can only create an account from a device? If he tries to create 2 accounts from the device, an alert dialog will be shown?

I was thinking to use database by getting the device id. But can any one tell me in details?

Comment: Have you read this? https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids.html#working_with_instance_ids_&_guids

Comment: yes! But where do I store InstanceID?

Answer (score 0):

You have to select your A&A provider (Authentication and Authorization).
Of course you could manage it yourself if you choose.

Firebase is a good free option to setup.
Simply write the screens to gather the user's info and supply a login screen. Then use the firebase API for signing up the user and logging in.

Another good option is Cognito on AWS, but requires a bit more understanding of AWS then Firebase does, so I would say firebase is easier for someone newer to A&A process.

If you don't want to manage a login, you could get the device advertiser ID and store that as the userId so that it only registers the device one time, but be warned, if the user really wants to jump all the hoops they can reset it from their Google Settings, although, it is extremely unlikely that anyone would or even know how letalone what it is lol. Using Device ID directly or telephone ID is no longer acceptable for Android unique id.

So to make sure they can't login on new device with same email just store the advertiser ID of the device with the username or email.

Then make sure on subsequent logins that you always confirm the advertiserID along with the username/password before allowing them to move on. You can validate user/pass first, then before moving on validate user/advertiserID or other order. Whatever you prefer.

```
AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(getApplicationContext()).getId();
```

Ok so your LoginScreen has a button to login

```
btnLogin_onClick(){
    validateSingleAccountForDevice(false);

}
btnCreateAccount_onClick(){
    validateSingleAccountForDevice(true);

}
validateSingleAccountForDevice(final boolean isCreatingAccount){
    String id = AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(getApplicationContext()).getId();
    String username = txtEmail.getText.toString();
    new ValidateSingleDeviceForEmailAsyncTask(){
          protected void onPostExecute(successModel model){
               if(model.isSuccess){
                    if(isCreatingAccount){
                        attemptCreateAccount();
                    }else{
                        attemptLogin();
                    }
               }else{
                    showAlertDialogOfAccountAlreadyUsedOnAnotherDevice();
               }
          }   
    };
}
private void attemptLogin(){
    String username = txtEmail.getText.toString();
    String password = txtPassword.getText.toString();
    new LoginWithUserPass(username, password){
          protected void onPostExecute(successModel model){
               if(model.isSuccess){
                    moveToLandingPage();
               }else{
                    showAlertOfFailedLogin();
               }
          }   
    };
}
private void createAccount(){
     String username = txtEmail.getText.toString();
    String password = txtPassword.getText.toString();
    new CreateAccountForUser(username, password){
          protected void onPostExecute(successModel model){
               if(model.isSuccess){
                    moveToLandingPage(); //or MFA if using
               }else{
                    showAlertOfFailedCreate();
               }
          }   
    };
}
```

Does that all make sense?

These asyncTask are "madeup" Make your own that does an Async call to a restful API to validate the email with device and your own that does the Login. Your question was not "how do I write an AsyncTask or How do I log a user in, so I did not supply asyncTasks to those things as you have not provided enough information for me to even do that, plus that is not the goal of my answer.

I merely gave an example of what it would look like if you wrote the code to hit an API and return inside of an Asynctask. If you are not familiar with async tasks, please do some research, this is not meant to be your fully functioning software solution.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156195/discussion-on-answer-by-sam-a-user-can-only-create-an-account-from-a-device).